Я делал login для сайта, но django пишет, что шаблона нет
Трейсбек выглядит следующим образом:
TemplateDoesNotExist at /users/login/
registration/login.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/users/login/
Django Version: 5.1.4
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
registration/login.html
Exception Location: E:\forum_site\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py, 
line 47, in select_template
Raised during:  django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView
Python Executable:  E:\forum_site\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.13.0
Python Path:    
['E:\\forum_site',
 'C:\\Users\\MSI\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python313\\python313.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\MSI\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python313\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\MSI\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python313\\Lib',
 'C:\\Users\\MSI\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python313',
 'E:\\forum_site\\venv',
 'E:\\forum_site\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 27 Dec 2024 08:33:20 +0000

Когда я делал сайт раньше, такого не было
папка с темплейтами:



Первая картинка в приложении users вторая forums
